# Is there a way to import Replit INTO GitHub?

Tags: github, import, transfer, replit

I have a large project on [Replit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replit) that I cannot find a way to import into GitHub.

I have tried to find tutorials online, but all are for the older version of Replit, *repl.it*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Replit has built in Git. Here is how to do it.

Inside your project, select Git under tools:

[image: Image showing the location of the Git button]

Next, select *initialize repository* to set up the Git repository:

[image: Image showing the location of the init repository button]

Then, press the settings gear:

[image: Image showing the location of the settings gear]

Finally, add your GitHub repository link and follow the instructions:

[image: Image showing where to add the link]