# Uploading Coding files from Repl.it to GitHub

Tags: github, replit

I am taking a coding class through my local college. Our professor has us using Repl.it to create our apps and sites. He has requested we upload our repl's to Github and provide the link. I have been able to create the repository but when I click to my Github dashboard no code is actually uploaded to it.

I tried to initialize through Repl.it and the repository is created but no code will actually be put inside of that repository.[This is what shows when I click on the repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B579f.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to import replit INTO github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75679103/is-there-a-way-to-import-replit-into-github)

Comment: @InSync i looked at this post already but the problem is not the initializing of the repository its that the code will not show inside of the repository. No code is actually inside of it

Comment: Did you *push* local changes onto the remote repo (e.g. using `git push`)?

Comment: @InSync I just did and it worked thank you